# Valor de data esta vindo 01/01/0001.00:00:00

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Estou tendo um problema com minha API quando tento resgatar uma data De uma coluna em minha tabela no SqlServer

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand()) {
                        command.Connection = connection;
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 DateStart, DateEnd from CheckUP where DeviceIMEI = @imei ORDER BY DateStart DESC";
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("imei", obj.DeviceIMEI);
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read()) {
                            CheckUP check = new CheckUP() {
                                DateStart = reader["DateStart"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateStart"]),
                                DateEnd = reader["DateEnd"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateEnd"]),
                            };

                            if (reader.IsDBNull(1) == true) {
                                System.DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

                                Debug.WriteLine("hoje"+ today);
                                Debug.WriteLine("data do banco" +  checkup.DateStart);

                                TimeSpan diferenceToday = today - checkup.DateStart;
                                totalLifeCheckUpProgress = diferenceToday.ToString();
                                Debug.WriteLine("Resultado"+totalLifeCheckUpProgress);
                            } else {
                                TimeSpan difetenceEnd = checkup.DateStart - checkup.DateEnd;
                                totalLifeCheckUpProgress = difetenceEnd.ToString();
                                Debug.WriteLine(totalLifeCheckUpProgress);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Pelo que entendo este valor que esta sendo retornado **01/01/0001.00:00:00**
deveria estasendo retornado somente se o valor for null ou menor que 01/01/1970

mas o valor do camnpo onde estou resgatando não é nullo nem me nor que 01/01/1970

o tipo de dado no banco de dados está como **smalldateTime**

o que posso está errando ?

Comment: DbNull.Value vai dar true se tiver valor, tal que vai colocar o seu min ali, você está confundindo o ternário

Comment: @LucasMiranda Realmente, estava confundindo 
Obrigado pelo dica.

Comment: @GabrielSilva Você jpa encontrou solução? Caso não teria como mandar um DER da tabela que está sendo executada e mais informações